# How to store null values in var in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
 var img2 = document.getElementById('ImgCorrectConditon2');//img2 = null
 img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

If its a null. exception / error occurs and next line of codes not executing. How to stop executing line of code if any, control is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check for `null`?

```
if(img2 != null) {
   img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code by checking img2 is not `null`

```
 var img2 = document.getElementById('ImgCorrectConditon2');//img2 = null
 if(img2 != null )
 {  
      img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }
```

Comment: The condition could be: if (img2).

Comment: @ConnorsFan you are right :). just for who asked he wrote he not expert just because of that

Comment: i need if image null also it should hide. and if it is visible also it should hide. at any cost it should hide.